# Save Pandas or Pyspark dataframe from Databricks to Azure Blob Storage

Tags: pandas, azure, pyspark, azure-blob-storage, databricks

Is there a way I can save a Pyspark or Pandas dataframe from Databricks to a blob storage without mounting or installing libraries?

I was able to achieve this after mounting the storage container into Databricks and using the library **com.crealytics.spark.excel**, but I was wondering if I can do the same without the library or without mounting because I will be working on clusters without these 2 permissions.

Comment: it depends on the format you want to save. Like, excel isn't built-in library on Databricks

Comment: Using the mount point is the best way to achieve exporting dataframes to a blob storage. 
The other and hard way would be using azure rest api for blob or the ```azure-storage-blob``` python library
The steps would be :
- 1 Save your dataframe locally on databricks dbfs
- 2 Connect to the blob storage using the API or the python library
- 3 Upload the local file stored in dbfs into the blob storage

Comment: Thank you @YassineELB, can you please provide a sample of code for these 2 approaches? I have been searching but I can't find anything useful

Comment: I made an answer with sample codes that i tried and it works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the code for saving the dataframe locally to dbfs.

```py
# export 
from os import path

folder = "export"
name = "export"
file_path_name_on_dbfs = path.join("/tmp", folder, name)

# Writing to DBFS
# .coalesce(1) used to generate only 1 file, if the dataframe is too big this won't work so you'll have multiple files qnd you need to copy them later one by one
sampleDF \
  .coalesce(1) \
      .write \
      .mode("overwrite") \
      .option("header", "true") \
      .option("delimiter", ";") \
      .option("encoding", "UTF-8") \
      .csv(file_path_name_on_dbfs)

# path of destination, which will be sent to az storage
dest = file_path_name_on_dbfs + ".csv"

# Renaming part-000...csv to our file name
target_file = list(filter(lambda file: file.name.startswith("part-00000"), dbutils.fs.ls(file_path_name_on_dbfs)))
if len(target_file) > 0:
  dbutils.fs.mv(target_file[0].path, dest)
  dbutils.fs.cp(dest, f"file://{dest}") # this line is added for community edition only cause /dbfs is not recognized, so we copy the file locally
  dbutils.fs.rm(file_path_name_on_dbfs,True)
```

The code that will send the file into az storage :

```py
import requests

sas="YOUR_SAS_TOKEN_PREVIOUSLY_CREATED" # follow the link below to create SAS token (using sas is slightly more secure than raw key storage) 
blob_account_name = "YOUR_BLOB_ACCOUNT_NAME"
container = "YOUR_CONTAINER_NAME"
destination_path_w_name = "export/export.csv"
url = f"https://{blob_account_name}.blob.core.windows.net/{container}/{destination_path_w_name}?{sas}"

# here we read the content of our previously exported df -> csv
# if you are not on community edition you might want to use /dbfs + dest
payload=open(dest).read()

headers = {
  'x-ms-blob-type': 'BlockBlob',
  'Content-Type': 'text/csv' # you can change the content type according to your needs
}

response = requests.request("PUT", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

# if response.status_code is 201 it means your file was created successfully
print(response.status_code)
```

[Follow this link to setup a SAS token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/applied-ai-services/form-recognizer/create-sas-tokens?view=form-recog-3.0.0#use-the-azure-portal)

Remember that anyone who got the sas token can access your storage depending on permissions you set while creating the sas token

#### Code for Excel export version (using com.crealytics:spark-excel_2.12:0.14.0)

Saving the dataframe :

```py
data = [ 
 ('a',25,'ast'),
 ('b',15,'phone'),
 ('c',32,'dlp'),
 ('d',45,'rare'),
 ('e',60,'phq' )
      ]
colums = ["column1" ,"column2" ,"column3"]
sampleDF = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema = colums)
sampleDF.show()

# export 
from os import path
folder = "export"
name = "export"
file_path_name_on_dbfs = path.join("/tmp", folder, name)

# Writing to DBFS
sampleDF.write.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")\
  .option("header", "true")\
  .mode("overwrite")\
  .save(file_path_name_on_dbfs + ".xlsx")

# excel
dest = file_path_name_on_dbfs + ".xlsx"
dbutils.fs.cp(dest, f"file://{dest}") # this line is added for community edition only cause /dbfs is not recognized, so we copy the file locally
```

Uploading the file to azure storage :

```py
import requests

sas="YOUR_SAS_TOKEN_PREVIOUSLY_CREATED" # follow the link below to create SAS token (using sas is slightly more secure than raw key storage) 
blob_account_name = "YOUR_BLOB_ACCOUNT_NAME"
container = "YOUR_CONTAINER_NAME"
destination_path_w_name = "export/export.xlsx"
# destination_path_w_name = "export/export.csv"
url = f"https://{blob_account_name}.blob.core.windows.net/{container}/{destination_path_w_name}?{sas}"

# here we read the content of our previously exported df -> csv
# if you are not on community edition you might want to use /dbfs + dest
# payload=open(dest).read()
payload=open(dest, 'rb').read()

headers = {
  'x-ms-blob-type': 'BlockBlob',
#   'Content-Type': 'text/csv'
   'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
}

response = requests.request("PUT", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

# if response.status_code is 201 it means your file was created successfully
print(response.status_code)
```

Comment: Thank you!
How can you use this with excel because I'm getting this error when reading the file
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x9a in position 12: invalid start byte
Also will the content type be the same?

Comment: I've edited the code for Excel, you will find it in the section : Code for Excel export version (using com.crealytics:spark-excel_2.12:0.14.0)